# $R[\mathbb Z]\cong R[X,Y]/(1-XY)$ and $R[\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z]\cong R[X]/(X^m-1)$

Tags: ring-theory

Proof: $R[\mathbb Z]\cong R[X,Y]/(1-XY)$ and $R[\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z]\cong R[X]/(X^m-1)$, where R is a commutative ring with one.

I cant help myself at the moment and I got headache! Please give me some tips (NO full answers please!)! I would be especially thankful for the intuition of these rings! $R[\mathbb Z]$ seems kind of absurd if I think about its multiplication.

I guess there are very easy surjective homomorphisms from the standard polynomial rings into the other monoid rings.

Comment: What is $R(x)$ and $R[X,1/X]$? $R[M]$, where $R$ is a commutative ring with one and $M$ is a commutative monoid is the polynom ring defined as usual. So $R[M]=\{(a_v)_{v\in M}|a_v\in R, a_v\neq0$ only for finetley many $v\}$, addition pointwise, multiplication $c_v=\sum \limits_{x+y=v} a_x*b_v$

Comment: The notation here is that $R[G]$ is the group ring of the group $G$ over the ring $R$.  I assume that this is the case because with this interpretation both those isomorphisms are true.

Comment: Yup, @PedroTamaroff. I wasn't paying enough attention in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $R[\mathbb Z]$ means the group ring of the additive group of $\mathbb Z$.

**Hint:** These rings are easy enough that the best way to do this is probably to just define ring homomorphisms in either direction and show that the composition in either direction is the identity.  The universal properties of these rings will help:

1) Any group homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to A^\ast$ (where $A$ is an $R$-algebra and $A^\ast$ is its group of units) uniquely extends to a ring homomorphism $R[\mathbb Z] \to A$.

2) Homomorphisms $R[x, y] \to A$ (where $A$ is an $R$-algebra) are uniquely and freely determined by choosing where $x$ and $y$ map to.

3) Any ring homomorphism $R[x, y] \to A$ whose kernel contains the ideal $I \subseteq R[x, y]$ factors uniquely to a homomorphism $R[x, y]/I \to A$.

Comment: Thanks! Ill try my luck tomorrow! Do you have any intuition on the ring $R[\mathbb Z]$ you could share?

Comment: I think of it as the ring of Lauraunt polynomials $R[x, \frac1x]$.

Comment: Ok, I think this is going to help me! But I still cant really get around that if I multiply $f*g=c, f,g\in R[\mathbb Z]$ each coefficient of $c$ is depending on all of the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, so they all interact.

Comment: Why is that a problem?