# Isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[C_n]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^n-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings, ring-isomorphism

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[C_n] \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^n-1)$ where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$. Let $t$ be a generator of $C_n$. There is a unique ring homomorphism

$$\Phi:\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[C_n]$$
sending $X$ to $t$. Obviously $(X^n-1) \subseteq \ker \Phi$. Let $f = \sum_{i=0}^m a_iX^i$ be in the kernel of $\Phi$. If $m \leq n-1$, then clearly $a_i = 0$ for all $i$, hence $f = 0$. Otherwise we have $m > n-1$ and applying $\Phi$ to $f$ we see that
$$-\sum_{i=0}^{m-n}a_{i+n}t^i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_it^i.$$
From here on I tried to find a suitable polynomial g in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $g(X)(X^n-1) = f$ but failed. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ denotes the group ring over $G$, i.e. the ring of all finite linear combinations $\sum_{g}a_gg$ where $a_g \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g \in G$.

Comment: This amounts to using the definition of $\mathbb Z[G],$ and depends on the exact wording of that definition, so if you could give us the definition you are using.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643144/why-does-f-langle-g-rangle-cong-fx-xn-1?rq=1) answer your question? That's with a field instead of $\mathbb Z$, but that doesn't change anything in the proof.

Comment: $g(X^n-1)$ is slightly ambiguous  - it could mean $g$ applied to $X^2-1,$ or $g(X)\cdot(X^n-1).$ The latter is what you mean. To prove $g$ exists, use division algorithm on $\mathbb Z[X],$ which is allowed only for *monic* divisor polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x],$ but luckily $X^n-1$ is monic.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Added the definition of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$.

Comment: That's not really a good definition., even if it is a good intuition. We'd define the addition group of the group ring to be the free abelian group on $G,$ and then we'd need to define the multiplication.

Comment: In general, for finite groups $G,$ we can define the group ring as the set of all functions $f:G\to\mathbb Z$ with addition: $(f_1+f_2)(g)=f_1(g)+f_2(g)$ and multiplication $$(f_1\cdot f_2)(g)=\sum_{g_1g_2=g} f_1(g_1)f_2(g_2).$$ (For infinite groups, we take all such functions with $f^{-1}(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})$ finite.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for the suggestions, especially applying the division algorithm on $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, I totally forgot that it applies to monic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$. As for your suggestion concerning the definition of the group ring, that's just the definition we use in our lecture. Nonetheless, thank you for the insight!

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163249/prove-that-the-group-ring-mathbbz-mathbbz-n-can-be-generated-by-a-sin?noredirect=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101607/r-mathbb-z-cong-rx-y-1-xy-and-r-mathbb-z-m-mathbb-z-cong-rx-xm-1?noredirect=1).